# How to call a function with argument Archive & ar?

Tags: c++

I have a class myclass and a function serialize. i am unable to call function of myclass.

**Function declaration in class:**

```
        class myclass
        {
        int x,y,z;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int=0 );

        }

        Function Definition:
        template<class Archive>void  myclass::serialize( Archive & ar,
                                                  const unsigned int)
        {
                ar & x;
                ar & y;
                ar & z;
        }
```

How to call the function serialize?  I have tried to call it like this:

```
myclass obj;  //object of my class
boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(std::cout);
obj.serialize (ar); //calling serialize
```

But is is giving me the below error:
 undefined reference to `void myclass::serialize

Comment: If that definition isn't in the same translation unit, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: That is not the issue. Undefined reference is due to there is some mismatch in the parameter of the function i am calling and the actual function.

I have tried n modified the argument of the same func and the  called it. There is no undefined reference then.

Comment: Well, it would be an issue. Defining function templates in a different "file" will not work. As seen in the link, there are plenty of ways to trigger that linker error, and a mismatch in parameter vs argument would more likely be a compiler error.